# Persistant object in ADF

Tags: google-project-tango

I am trying to formulate how to create an ADF, drop an object in it, then have that object always be there when I run the app again, after localization occurs, of course. Do I have to save off the locations of virtual objects into a separate file when the user is done "dropping" objects into the scene and then reload them on subsequent runs? Or is there a way to save them into the ADF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good way to save it into ADF, unless you hack some of the ADF's meta data. But hacking meta data is not suggested.

Comment: So, saving off the X,Y,Z locations to a file, then loading that file back at run time is the way to go?

Comment: Yes, correct. Actually if you look into the AreaLearning example in Unity, that's how we did it too. Here is the line saving xml: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/AreaLearning/Scripts/AreaLearningInGameController.cs#L149

Answer (score 1):

We cannot save objects with ADF, instead while loading ADF, object can be added (after recognition of ADF) to the recognised coordinate.

I did something like this and got it working, but found placed objects oscillating and not get placed exactly on the same place in the subsequent ADF loading. Because whenever Tango connection is established, that location is considered as origin(0,0,0) and objects get placed related to this origin. So it is hard to see those objects exactly on same places.

Answer (score 0):

I did what you say. 
You have to write coordinates of Objects into a separated file then when you reload scene and recognized your room (thanks to the adf), just put back objects at same coords.

Of course every coord (x y z) must refer to the ADF Tango pose -> base = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION

On Unity it's very simple, you just have to check to "true" the "Use Area description poses" on your ARCamera tango script and same on your PointCloud script if you use it also.